# Ender 3 BLTouch working but with random red flashing?

Tags: bltouch

I've got an Ender 3 with 1.1.4 mainboard - recently bought a Creality BLTouch (v2 because of the 8-bit board), fitted, flashed the firmware (1.1.6) and all appears to be working... however...

I get random 'red flashing' during the auto bed leveling process, I can't spot a particular pattern, and it doesn't always react the same way. In a majority of cases, the BLTouch starts flashing and appears to pause and then retries and carries on. It's almost as if there's a communications issue and it has to perform a mini-reset and then retries.  I've had a couple of occasions where it's thrown the bed leveling out completely, but the majority of the time it manages to keep going and works.

I'm trying to work out where the issue is, if it was bad wiring, I'd expect it to happen on a much more regular basis. As it is, I'll get one clean run in about five. And when there's an issue, it's at a single (random) point in the nine probe points.

I'm suspicious that the issue is a timing issue because the board is an 8-bit board and possibly an issue with the firmware? I'm very tempted to try out other Marlin firmware versions, or possibly even Klipper (I've got a Pi 4 running OctoPrint).

Just wondering if anyone has any thoughts on this or steps to diagnose/put right.